# xls to mysql with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv

I've an xls file with this type:

```
group_name | name
my_groupe1 | name1
my_groupe4 | name2
my_groupe2 | name3
my_groupe1 | name4
```

and my database:

```
    users
id | id_group | name
```

and

```
    groups
id | name
```

I would like export my xls data in my database. But i must replace "group_name" by his id of the real record in database.

All group record already exist in my database.

I've think to make an webservice for this but i prefer export it directly.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to create dynamic SQL INSERT statements in Excel based on your data.  Below I gave you the formula for D2 and E2.

**D2:**
="INSERT INTO group (id,name) VALUES (*,'" & B2 & "')"

**BECOMES:**

INSERT INTO group (id,name) VALUES (*,'my_group1')

**E2:**
="INSERT INTO user (id,name,group) VALUES (*,'" & B2 & "'," & A2 & ")"

**BECOMES:**

INSERT INTO user (id,name,group) VALUES (*,'my_group1',1)

[image]

Comment: I think the OP doesn't have a groupid column in his Excel sheet - that info is only in the Database... so you have to add a database lookup for the groupid into your SQL statement.

Comment: My answer is more of a methodology.  I'll leave the details to him to figure out.  I'm sure he can just do a select query and plop those into the spreadsheet for reference.